# Meta-analysis - PRISMA 2020 checklist

Tags: meta-analysis, psychology

SYNTHESIS METHODS (eligibility for synthesis)
13a
• Describe the processes used to decide which studies were eligible for each synthesis.

My study aims to compare Internet Delivered Mindfulness Based Interventions with Treatment as Usual or other Active Interventions delivered face-to-face for cancer patients undergoing cancer treatment. My research questions are -

1. Do online mindfulness-based interventions (eMBIs) demonstrate superior efficacy compared to treatment as usual (TAU) in mitigating the psychological and physical health effects associated with cancer and its therapy?
2. How does the efficacy of eMBIs compare to that of face-to-face mindfulness-based interventions and other active therapies in addressing the psychological and physical health implications of cancer and its treatment?
3. Are there significant differences in the effectiveness of self-guided and mobile/telephone-provided eMBIs in addressing the psychological and physical health implications of cancer and its treatment?
4. Do long-term benefits of eMBIs persist in terms of improved psychological well-being and reduced physical symptoms in cancer patients?

Is it okay if, when describing the process used to decide which studies were eligible for each synthesis, I simply say - The eligibility of studies for inclusion in the synthesis was systematically determined through a meticulous evaluation of the alignment between the interventions employed in each study and the research questions. Clear inclusion and exclusion criteria were established a priori, encompassing aspects such as study design, participant characteristics, interventions, and outcomes. The synthesis of results entailed performing a meta-analysis to estimate the overall effect size of online mindfulness interventions for patients undergoing cancer treatment. The analysis also aimed to observe the effectiveness of eMBIs compared to treatment as usual (TAU)/Waitlist control, assess the efficiency of eMBIs compared to other active interventions, examine the efficacy of telephone/computer/app-based MBIs versus guided self-help mindfulness interventions, and explore the effectiveness of eMBIs across different time-points. ?

Comment: Is it OK for what medium?

Comment: Simple answer - No. That shouldn't pass peer-review or meet the criteria of PRISMA. Take a look at published Cochrane reviews and see how they report these aspects. There is a lot of details that you are missing in your description that a peer-reviewer (or reader) would be interested in.

Comment: If you write that and submit to a leading health journal it is liable to lead to instant rejection. As @abousetta suggests you need to tell us exactly what you did in enough detail to enable us to reproduce it.